# WebApi 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am experimenting with WebApi and have created a controller with two methods.

I started with the following method first:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("car/{registration}")]
    public object GetCarByRegistration(string registration) {
        return null;
    }
```

When debugging I put a breakpoint on `return null;` tested url `http://localhost:51245/api/car/yw25jdk` which work fine, visual studio stopped at my breakpoint and the `registration` variable was the same value in the url.

But when I added the following method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("car/{serial}")]
    public object GetCarBySerial(string serial) {
        return null;
    }
```

The first url stopped working and I started to get `500 - Internal Server Error`. If I take the second method out then the first method works again.

I cannot understand why the second method breaks the first one.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: the routes are identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well thats because ASP does not know which method to use when you go to the url  `http://localhost:51245/api/car/yw25jdk` since both methods say they expect a string as their parameter.

How should ASP know the difference between `/car/{registration}` and `/car/{serial]`, since both of them are string?

You should change the Route of on of them, to get it working

Comment: duhh, I feel so silly, It's so obvious now. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your WebApiConfig:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Otherwise WebApi ignores the Route attribute. And without the different route signatures, when the ApiController receives a **GET** request, it automatically looks for the first action that starts with 'Get' - this is why it works when you remove the second method

Comment: He probably has that. Because it is working with just one of them. The Problem that it is exactly the same route